# How to call Elastic Search for current queue load?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, queue

While querying ES extensively, I get

```
Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@59e634e2] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.search.
action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@75bd024b
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.execute(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.execute(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:551)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:83)
```

on a quite regular basis.

My plan, now, is to `pause` the query requests until the queue load is lower than `x`. You can query the client for its `stats`

```
client.admin().cluster().threadPool().stats().iterator();
```

But since my client is not a data node (I presume that's why), I get `queue=0` returned, while the server node throw the above error.

I know why this gets thrown, and I know how to update the setting, but that just postpones this error, and creates others...

**How do I ask the cluster nodes what their queue load is?**

*PS: I'm using the Java Api*

What I've tried, without requested result, blank line indicative of another try, unless otherwise specifiied

```
//Nodes stats
final NodesStatsResponse nodesStatsResponse = client.admin().cluster().prepareNodesStats().execute().actionGet();
final NodeStats nodeStats = nodesStatsResponse.getNodes()[0];
final String nodeId = nodeStats.getNode().getId(); // need this later on

// same as before, but with explicit NodesStatsRequest (with id)
final NodesStatsResponse response = client.admin().cluster().nodesStats(new NodesStatsRequest(nodeId)).actionGet();
final NodeStats[] nodeStats2 = response.getNodes();
for (NodeStats nodeStats3 : nodeStats2) {
    Stats stats = nodeStats3.getThreadPool().iterator().next();
}

// Cluster?
final ClusterStatsRequest clusterStatsRequest = new ClusterStatsRequestBuilder(client.admin().cluster()).request();
final ClusterStatsResponse clusterStatsResponse = client.admin().cluster().clusterStats(clusterStatsRequest).actionGet();
final ClusterStatsNodes clusterStatsNodes = clusterStatsResponse.getNodesStats();

// Nodes info?
final NodesInfoResponse infoResponse = client.admin().cluster().nodesInfo(new NodesInfoRequest(nodeId)).actionGet();// here
final NodeInfo[] nodeInfos = infoResponse.getNodes();
for (final NodeInfo nodeInfo : nodeInfos) {
    final ThreadPoolInfo info = nodeInfo.getThreadPool();
    final Iterator<Info> infoIterator = info.iterator();
    while (infoIterator.hasNext()) {
        final Info realInfo = infoIterator.next();
        SizeValue sizeValue = realInfo.getQueueSize();
        // is no == null, then (¿happens?, was expecting a nullpointer, but Thread disappeared)
        if (sizeValue == null) 
            continue;
        // normal queue size, no load (oddly found 1000 (expected), and one of 200 in one node?)
        final long queueSize = sizeValue.getSingles(); 
    }
}
```

The issue is that some of the processes need to be called instantly (e.g. user requests), whereas others may wait if the database is too busy (background processes). Preferably, I'd assign a certain amount of the queue to processes that stand on immediate requests, and the other part on background processes (but I haven't seen this option).

**Update**
It appears, which I didn't expect, that you can get a query overload with a single bulk query, when the total amount of separate searches exceed 1000 (when x shards, or x indices, divide by 1000/x for the number of searches). So bulking,,, not an option, unless you can make a `single` query. So when you target on 700 search results at once (taking in account the above statement), you'll need to know whether more than 300 items reside in the queue, for then it'll throw stuff.

**To sum up:**

Assume the load, per call, is the maximum `bulkrequest` so I cannot combine requests. How, then, can I start pausing requests **before** elasticsearch starts throwing the above stated exception. So I can pause a part of my application, but not the other? If I know the queue is filled, say, half way, the background process must sleep some time. How do I know the (approximated) queue load?

Comment: I also remember reading that 10-15mb is a good size for bulk requests, how big are the bulks you are putting through now?

Comment: @IanGabes (I though 100MB is limit by default), it depends but I'd say - for the most part - < 5 KB (+- 100 words per call). Although some bigger requests may come through. I'm afraid I have to rewrite the way I call the search/update/insert calls (to create pools of requests :s)... Because the `answer` I'm **not** proposing, sounds horrible.

Comment: With sizes less than 5kb, that is a lot of overhead, you should try sending heavier requests, at least in the MB range.

Comment: @IanGabes that's a backup plan... But I'd rather let my system wait a couple of seconds (for the background process), instead of buffering the threads. (still hoping that a solution for my question exists, not a workaround - bugfix) If this `problem`  is handled by enlarging these queries, I'll come up with something else to upset the server... Better fix is onforehand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are trying to look at the queue usage is wrong, as you are not looking at the correct statistics.

Have a look at this piece of code:

```
    final NodesStatsResponse response = client.admin().cluster().prepareNodesStats().setThreadPool(true).execute().actionGet();
    final NodeStats[] nodeStats2 = response.getNodes();

    for (NodeStats nodeStats3 : nodeStats2) {
        ThreadPoolStats stats = nodeStats3.getThreadPool();

        if (stats != null)
            for (ThreadPoolStats.Stats threadPoolStat : stats) {
                System.out.println("node `" + nodeStats3.getNode().getName() + "`" + " has pool `" + threadPoolStat.getName() + "` with current queue size " + threadPoolStat.getQueue());
            }
    }
```

First of all you need `setThreadPool(true)` to be able to get back the thread pool statistics otherwise it will be `null`.

Secondly, you need `ThreadPoolStats` not `ThreadPoolInfo` which is for thread pool settings.

So, it's your second attempt, but incomplete. The `1000` you were seeing was the setting itself (the max queue size), not the actual load.

Comment: Nice! Apparently, each different kind of operation has its on queue, like: `search`, `get`, `bulk`... Any idea if this call creates some sort of overhead? If, for instance, I'd ask the nodes their queues each second?

Comment: Yes, exactly, [different thread pools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-threadpool.html#modules-threadpool) for a lot of things. Related to overhead - yes, obviously, there is an overhead but I don't think there will be much. Any way of testing this and see how much these calls every second are affecting the cluster? But do this for a longer period of time and monitor the cluster while doing it.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do that, but the service is not that predictable (the server load is heavily dependent on external sources), and nothing get ran twice. Nor do I have additional `es` packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **hoping** this is **not** the answer, source https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html#_threadpool_section:

> Bulk Rejections
>
> If you are going to encounter queue rejections, it will most likely be
>   caused by bulk indexing requests. It is easy to send many bulk
>   requests to Elasticsearch by using concurrent import processes. More
>   is better, right?
>
> In reality, each cluster has a certain limit at which it can not keep
>   up with ingestion. Once this threshold is crossed, the queue will
>   quickly fill up, and new bulks will be rejected.
>
> This is a good thing. Queue rejections are a useful form of back
>   pressure. They let you know that your cluster is at maximum capacity,
>   which is much better than sticking data into an in-memory queue.
>   Increasing the queue size doesn’t increase performance; it just hides
>   the problem. If your cluster can process only 10,000 docs per second,
>   it doesn’t matter whether the queue is 100 or 10,000,000—your cluster
>   can still process only 10,000 docs per second.
>
> The queue simply hides the performance problem and carries a real risk
>   of data-loss. Anything sitting in a queue is by definition not
>   processed yet. If the node goes down, all those requests are lost
>   forever. Furthermore, the queue eats up a lot of memory, which is not
>   ideal.
>
> It is much better to handle queuing in your application by gracefully
>   handling the back pressure from a full queue. When you receive bulk
>   rejections, you should take these steps:
>
> Pause the import thread for 3–5 seconds. Extract the rejected actions
>   from the bulk response, since it is probable that many of the actions
>   were successful. The bulk response will tell you which succeeded and
>   which were rejected. Send a new bulk request with just the rejected
>   actions. Repeat from step 1 if rejections are encountered again. Using
>   this procedure, your code naturally adapts to the load of your cluster
>   and naturally backs off.
>
> Rejections are not errors: they just mean you should try again later.

Particularly this `When you receive bulk rejections, you should take these steps` I don't like. We should be able to handle oncoming problems on forehand.